# How to generate arbitrally large mermaid diagram in local? Error: "Maximum text size diagram exceeded"

Tags: graph, markdown, mermaid

I have a bunch of data from which i'm generating a text file to encode a mermaid diagram.
But since this text file so big: 2000 lines. It won't generate an svg on the live version of https://mermaid.live/edit.
I then tried to install the mermaid http-server using docker, with no success (https://github.com/TomWright/mermaid-server).
Then, I wanted to try to use a local client but I have the same error: "Maximum text size diagram exceeded". (https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli)
So the prblem is that I can't generate an SVG file from my data.

I try to check if there were a configuration file in any of those mermaid "implementations" but i couldn't find one.
I checked previously asked similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they are outdated unfortunatly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by using this template and pasting the graph text inside the "mermaid" beacons: it works because the maxTextSize has been set to 10000000000.
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre class="mermaid">
    ...
    ...
    </pre>
    <script type="module">
      import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@9/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
      mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true, securityLevel: 'loose', maxTextSize: 10000000000,});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`